# Is Graph with multiple-inputs and multiple-outputs called MIMO?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, operations-research

MIMO (systems with multiple-inputs and multiple-outputs) is a term in engineering areas and applied mathematics such as process-control and wireless communication. Suppose you have a directed graph $G$ with multiple-inputs and multiple-outputs, can $G$ be called MIMO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went from engineering in telecommunications (where I heard a lot about MIMO systems) to operations research (where I saw lots of graph theory). To my knowledge, there is no definition of the terms "input" and "output" in graph theory that are currently used by the community, which means no MIMO. You may however look into:

- In directed graphs, a node with no children is usually called a terminal node.
- Automaton theory, there is the concept of start state (a node of a graph) and 
  accept node (another particular node)
- Bipartite (or n-partite) graphs (the MIMO and MIMO-MAC systems are usually represented by bipartite graphs).

What is the context in which you need this?